# spring mvc 3 and static content

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap with my spring web application.
Static content is not served. I've looked through bunch of answers on SO but still cannot resolve this.

*mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml*

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.indie.stock.controllers" />
 <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="250000"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*web.xml*

```
 <web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        classpath:com/indie/stock/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.indie.stock.filters.NoCacheFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in my jsps i'm refering to static content this way

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/ico/favicon.png">
```

[image]

What am I missing?

***EDIT: Here is what I get when I try to access static resource***

```
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/resources/1122.jpg]
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/1122.jpg
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 WARN  PageNotFound:194 - Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /favicon.ico
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:132 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 WARN  PageNotFound:194 - Request method 'GET' not supported
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2013-09-01 23:46:37 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: maybe you're missing context path of your webapp?

Comment: generally it's better to use `<c:url/>` or `<spring:url/>` to be sure it points where it should.

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: which spring version are you using and wich are the routes mapped? (you should see the routes in the log)

Comment: I use 3.2.3.RELEASE. What you mean by "wich are the routes mapped" ?

Comment: you should see a log similar to this: `HandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[...cut
Mapped "{[/page-not-found],methods=[],para....cut`
where all your routes are mapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was that one of my controller handler methods which was supposed to handle user registration forms was not annotated with request url but only with request method "POST". While debugging I noticed that this handler method was chosen to handle requests for resources. But since it handled POST requests only - as result I got HTTP status 405 "GET requests not supported".
So once I specified request url everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet-based web applications get deployed to some context, so that their every url has to have context name prepended.

In tomcat for example, by default the context is the same as the war file name unless the war is called `ROOT.war` (or unless you change context.xml and configure the name yourself). If it is `ROOT.war` then it's deployed at the root context.

To rule that problem out, try using

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"  href="<c:url value='/resources/bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/ico/favicon.png' />" />
```

It will automatically prepend the context name to the url, whatever it is.

Comment: didnt help. by the way when i try to access this resource i get HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: @user1745356 maybe you have another controller mapped to `/resources/` ??

Comment: no, i dont have controllers that map to /resources/. But I've noticed that if I try to access any url that is not handled by any controller i always get 405. Shouldn't I get 404?

Comment: @user1745356 set log level for spring mvc to DEBUG (`log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet=DEBUG` in case of log4j) and paste what it prints when you try to access static resources

Comment: according to log it seems that handler which shoud serve static content is not set up however it is defined in dispatcher-servlet context....

Answer (score 0):

Here it's a simple project with bootstrap working, so you can see what you are missing easily: https://github.com/m4nuv/easy-bank/tree/dev/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

this is a piece of the code used (the rest seems ok):

```
        <c:url value="/resources/bootstrap" var="bootstrap" />
        <spring:message var="siteTitle" code="site.title" />

        <title>${siteTitle}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="${bootstrap}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

        <link href="${bootstrap}/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

edit1:
(ok it's exactly the same soulcheck told you with just a piece of code you can look about, given you said the his hint didn't help)

edit2:
if you are using spring-security to secure your app be careful to remove the security from resources: `<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think your servlet mapping is wrong:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This mapping means that your dispatcher servlet is only going to serve request in the context path URL of your application (e.g. `/app-name/` or `/`. It should be like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So it can serve any URL in your app so your static content mappings are invoked in URLs like `/resources/bootstrap-3.0.0/**` are handled by your mvc-dispatcher servlet.

Comment: doesn't it change only the base pattern for the dispatcher servlet ?
update: I tried and it seems like it works well without the *

Comment: @EmanueleIvaldi i think it is working because the directory is outside of your /WEB-INF/ and the servlet container is resolving to the file, but your mvc-dispatcher servlet is not serving that request.

Comment: yep I tried the same  user1745356's config (his resources aren't inside the WEB-INF folder), doesn't should be the servlet container that serves the static resources (it's should be very fast doing that, shouldn't it?) ?

Comment: Yes, but the mvc:resources mapping was made for resources that the container cannot map this way e.g. resources inside a META-INF folder inside a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder of a web application.

Comment: Thank you for the infos, so I think that's not the container that's mapping the resources because if  I remove the `<mvc:resource>` tag the call to a resource ends in a 404

Comment: it shouldn't matter if the resources are in web app root, as long as spring dispatcher is mapped to `/`

Comment: it's one of the use cases of  `<mvc:resources/>`. You might want to have your api calls mapped directly too root and don't mind spring handling the static resources.